# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I've a lambda function as a Docker image in my ECR repository.
The lambda function just prints "Welcome" and nothing more.
I've set it up to be invoked whenever there is an S3 bucket activity.
When I upload a file to the S3 bucket, the lambda seem to be invoked but errors out as:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app' Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I can see the error in AWS lambda functions cloudwatch logs.

Below is my app.py

```
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('In app.py................................')

def handler(event, context) -> None:
    logger.info('Inside handler....Welcome')
    logger.info("Iam from app.py")
    logger.info('event: ', event)
    logger.info('context: ', context)
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
    --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
    -r requirements.txt \
    --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

I don't know if I ever need WORKDIR since LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT is anyway going to point to /var/task?
But the main issue is that "No module named app"

There is also a **requirements.txt** file but I am not using anything from it.

```
boto3>=1.24.1
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What does your working directory look like? Is `app.py` at the same level as the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I don't have any sub-directories. All the files (buildspec.yaml,Dockerfile,requirements.txt,app.py etc) are in the project level root dir.